# Flutter - Updated all Firebase Dependencies - Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, error-handling

I have a flutter project that I want to migrate to the newest dependencies (Firestore, FirebaseAuth, FirebaseStorage, etc.).

I migrated all the code and also updated my library to be able to launch the app. In a lot of my firebase collections I do not have defined fields and previously when I request from Firebase the field it just returns null. Now instead, it creates an error `Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform` which does not exist and the application cannot function properly.

I would appreciate solutions that would allow me to update my dependencies but not change the code base as much.

**Dependencies in Pubspec.yaml file:**

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.4
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.2.0
  curved_navigation_bar: ^1.0.1
  grouped_list: ^4.1.0
  random_color: ^1.0.6-nullsafety
  intl: ^0.17.0
  firebase_storage: ^10.1.0
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+4
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.4.1
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  csv: ^5.0.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.7
  excel: ^2.0.0-null-safety-3
  flutter_email_sender: ^5.0.2
  firebase_core: ^1.10.0
  firebase_messaging: ^11.1.0
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
  flutter_icons: ^1.1.0
  camera: ^0.9.4+4
  qr_code_scanner: ^0.6.1
  package_info: ^2.0.2
  url_launcher: ^6.0.13
```

**Example Streambuilder code:**

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: stream,
  builder: (ctx, queryDetailSnapShot) {
    if (queryDetailSnapShot.connectionState ==
        ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }

    var priceDetail = queryDetailSnapShot.data.docs;
    return ListView.builder(
        reverse: false,
        itemCount: priceDetail.length,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
          if (_selectedBottomIndex == 1) {
            return CostExpenseRequestContainer(
              widget.storenameUser,
              widget.storeCostAcess,
              widget.userName,
              widget.userEmail,
              widget.userId,
              widget.userLanguage,
              priceDetail[index]['Storename'],
              priceDetail[index]['Created_dt'],
              priceDetail[index]['Expense_type_en'],
              priceDetail[index]['Expense_type_th'],
              priceDetail[index]['Expense_amount_org'],
              priceDetail[index]['Expense_amount_approved'],
              priceDetail[index]['Visible_to'],
              priceDetail[index]['Expense_status'],
              priceDetail[index]['Photo_url'],
              priceDetail[index]['Service_dt'],
              priceDetail[index]['Partner_account_number'],
              priceDetail[index]['Partner_value_th'],
              priceDetail[index]['Partner_value_en'],
              priceDetail[index].id,
              key: ValueKey(priceDetail[index].id,),
            );
          } else
            return CostExpenseTrContainer(
              widget.storenameUser,
              widget.storeCostAcess,
              widget.userName,
              widget.userEmail,
              widget.userId,
              widget.userLanguage,
              priceDetail[index]['Storename'],
              priceDetail[index]['Created_dt'],
              priceDetail[index]['Service_dt'],
              priceDetail[index]['Expense_type_en'],
              priceDetail[index]['Expense_type_th'],
              priceDetail[index]['Expense_amount'],
              priceDetail[index]['Reversal_flg'],
              priceDetail[index]['Visible_to'],
              priceDetail[index].id,
              priceDetail[index]['Parent_record_id'],
              priceDetail[index]['Partner_account_number'],
              key: ValueKey(
                priceDetail[index].id,
              ),
            );
        });
  }),
```

**Error Message:**

```
Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

Earlier you had to call the field in document snapshot like this

```
docSnapshot['field']
```

But in the recent version, you have to call the data function to get the data as a map then access the required field. Example

```
docSnapshot.data()['field']
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the field that was creating an issue for me was `Partner_account_number`, I needed to check if the field exists before calling. This was the quickest fix I could find that need to apply throughout the application.

```
priceDetail[index].data().containsValue('Partner_account_number') ==true? 
priceDetail[index]['Partner_account_number']
:null
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).